# Accessing Values of a ForeignKey or OneToOne object in ModelForm

Tags: django

I have a `ModelFormA` for `ModelA`, which has a one-one relationship with `ModelB` and foreign-key relationship with `ModelC`.

Inside `ModelFormA`, I can access attributes of the current ModelA instance via `self.cleaned_data["colA-1"]`. How would I access attributes of ModelB or ModelC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the current values of the object, rather than the values submitted by the form, you actually need to use `self.instance`. You can then do `self.instance.myforeignkey` or whatever you need to follow relationships.

Answer (score 0):

self.cleaned_data["foreign_key_column"] actually returns an instance of the related model. Same goes for one-to-one relationship